# Why does Afghanistan use Solar Hijri calendar while they don't celebrate Nowruz as the new year day?

Tags: iran, afghanistan, public-holidays, tajikistan

I was reading the Wikipedia article for [Nowruz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowruz) and the first map caught my eye:

[image: Nowruz]

Iran is the only country that Nowruz is both a national holiday and the new year.

Afghanistan on the other hand just has Nowruz as a national holiday.

But both Iran and Afghanistan use Solar Hijri calendar (Persian calendar) (the only difference is in the name of months). Today is Shahrivar 23, 1402 in Iran and Sonboleh 23, 1402 in Afghanistan (Sonboleh is the Persian name for Virgo).

Why does Afghanistan use Solar Hijri calendar while they don't celebrate Nowruz as the new year?

Why doesn't Afghanistan celebrate Nowruz as the new year while they use Solar Hijri calendar which its start is on Farvardin 1 (Hamal* 1) in both Iran and Afghanistan? So what's the new year in Afghanistan? How do they go to the next year if they don't celebrate the new year?

I suspect Tajikistan also uses the Persian calendar but I'm not sure.

*Hamal is Arabic name for Taurus

Comment: Why do the English have Wednesday and Thursday if they're not pagan?

Comment: That's not relevant. The start of Persian calendar is "Farvardin 1" in both countries. Also the year in both countries is 1402.

Comment: If my question isn't about governments then how did Juhasz' answer speak about the Afghan government actions? Also, even without that answer my question is indeed about governments. It is because of a government that Nowruz isn't celebrated in Afghanistan. Isn't it?

Comment: **Voting to reopen** - why was this question closed at all? The calendar a country follows, and the decision to celebrate some day as an official holiday (or not) is very much  a political decision by the powers to be. This Q also has some good answers.

Answer (score 3):

Afghanistan does not currently use the Solar Hijri calendar.

> Kabul – Taliban regime has announced that all government communications will be based on the Hijri lunar calendar.
>
> According to a letter issued by the Administrative Office and instructed verbally by Taliban members, all administrative communications should be arranged based on the lunar year...
>
> Afghanistan’s fiscal year and the calendar were based on the solar year. From now on the Hijri Lunar calendar will be practiced.

[Taliban Changes Solar Year to Hijri Lunar Calendar](https://8am.media/eng/taliban-changes-solar-year-to-hijri-lunar-calendar/)

Prior to this ruling (1 Muharram 1444 AH; 8 Mordad 1401 SH; 30 July 2022 CE), Afghanistan did consider Nowruz to be the start of the new year.

Some people apparently still consider Nowruz to mark the new year, such as the US government:

> March
> Afghan New Year (Nawroz)
> Sunday, March 21

[U.S. Embassy in Afghanistan - Holiday Calendar](https://af.usembassy.gov/holiday-calendar/)

Or perhaps they just haven't updated their website since the embassy was closed.

As to why the Taliban uses this calendar, they are Pashtuns and fundamentalist
**Sunnis**, so they wouldn't use the Persian, Shia calendar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please add a little bit information about Tajikistan too? I suspect they use Gregorian calendar. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

As another answer has mentioned, the official calender in Afghanistan has changed to Lunar calender, the same rule was applied also till 2001.

But Tajikistan uses Gregorian Calender, there is a Wikipedia page, [in Persian](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA_%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%85%DB%8C%D8%AA_%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C_%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C_%D8%AF%D8%B1_%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%AC%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86) about *Application for officialization of solar calendar in Tajikistan*:

> The request for the officialization of the Hijri solar calendar in
> Tajikistan refers to the fact that the people of Tajikistan wanted to
> return to their own identity after the independence of this country,
> one of the examples of which is the request for the officialization of
> the solar Hijri calendar and the selection of Nowruz as the beginning
> of the new year in Tajikistan. Especially since the official calendar
> of two Farsi-speaking countries, Iran and Afghanistan, is Hijri, and
> Tajikistan is the only Persian-speaking country where the Gregorian
> calendar is official.
>
> This request of the people has remained silent until now due to
> Russian influence and the opposition of the Tajik government for
> economic, cultural and political reasons such as relations with Russia
> and other countries. Recently, the Tajik people have insisted on this
> request on the Internet and other media.
>
> Abdul Fattah Vahdouf, the director of the monitoring department of the
> Independent Media Association in Tajikistan, believes that there is no
> problem for the implementation of this plan because it has many fans.
> His only concern is the economic problems of the Tajik government,
> which may hinder the implementation of this plan. He says about this:
>
> "In today's Tajik society, there are various ideas that seek to
> implement this plan. But there are other problems in Tajikistan that
> create a practical obstacle to the implementation of this plan. This
> country is interested in and attached to the former Soviet Union.
> Since 90 years ago, we have passed from the Hijri calendar to the
> Gregorian calendar. Today, the dependence of Tajikistan and the
> community of former Soviet countries on other European countries that
> have a close relationship with us through the former Soviet Union
> creates problems on the way to change from the Gregorian calendar to
> the solar calendar.
>
> On the eve of Nowruz 1390, Imam Ali Rahman emphasized several times
> the beginning of the new year with Nowruz. At the same time, the
> official calendar of Tajikistan is still the Gregorian calendar, and
> the delivery of the new year in Dushanbe is still official. It seems
> that Tajiks will soon accept the solar calendar at least alongside
> their Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please clarify when Abdul Fattah Vahdouf told this "90 years ago..." thing?